# saving background-image to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a card memory game using react, where the cards are robots from http://robohash.org. My cards array looks like that:

```
{id: 0, cardState: CardState.1, backgroundImage: ''},
{id: 1, cardState: CardState.1, backgroundImage: ''},
```

since calling url("https://robohash.org/...") on every card using onClick takes ages, I'm trying to fetch the robots using axios.get, then save them to the state. However, no matter what I try, I cannot seem to get it to work.

My function looks like that (I have 16 cards, so I need 8 robots multiplied twice)

```
async fetchRobots() {
  let cards = [...this.state.cards];
  let robots = [...this.state.robots];
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    try {
      const resp = await axios.get(`https://robohash.org/${i}?size:150x150`);
      robots.push(resp.data, resp.data);
    } catch (e) {

    }
  }
  this.setState({
    cards: cards.map((card, i) => {
      card.backgroundImage = "url(data:image/png," + robots[i];
    })
  });
}
```

I've tried adding "base64" to the header, but it also doesn't work. Any way I can save the image to the state and let it show?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variant of solution

we will return image as **blob** and convert it to **base64**

```
function getBase64FromBlob(blob){
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
        reader.onloadend = function() {           
             resolve(reader.result);
        }
    });
}


async fetchRobots() {
  let cards = [...this.state.cards];
  let robots = [...this.state.robots];
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    try {
      const resp = await axios.get(`https://robohash.org/${i}?size:150x150`, {responseType:'blob'});
      const imgBase64 = await getBase64FromBlob(resp.data); // convert image to base64
      robots.push(imgBase64, imgBase64); // imgBase64 = "data:image/png;base64, ..."
    } catch (e) {

    }
  }
  this.setState({
    cards: cards.map((card, i) => {
      card.backgroundImage = "url(" + robots[i] + ")";
    })
  });
}
```

You can also use **imgBase64** as source for **img.src**

Answer (score 1):

State is immutable. You can't just push to objects on the state or update them as you might expect.

To change the state you need to call `this.setState({robots: yourArray});` for example which would update the state with your new array. This will then trigger a re-render in React whenever the state is modified.

Comment: Yes of course, I set it with setState. The problem is not getting the state to update (the cards array), but rather to show the background image.